Tiny Holes in a few hibiscus leaves. Also slight yellowing
What to do?  Hibiscus plants Tiny holes and slight yellowing on leaves. Looked like very small ants on the leaves. Also thought I saw a small small whitish spider

HI Holly, welcome to the site.  A few photos would help immensely.
